# User interface in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

How can I use an user interface (GUI) in Java ME? I followed some tutorials and all them point to the javax.microedition.lcdui package, but it just doesn't exist in Java ME 8 SDK.

Since I can't find that package, and SDK 3.4 gives me errors in Netbeans (I activate it and add it as platform, but it doesn't appear when I have to choose a simulation platform when creating a project.

You can see here how I don't have the LCDUI package:

[image]

I need some help in order to use GUIs in this Java version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know JavaME 8 is targeted at the embedded space and isn't supported on phones etc. It should have a profile without any UI elements and might have JavaFX embedded.

I am unaware of any device in the field that supports JavaME 8 but might be missing something.